# Search query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this problem an I need a solution:
In my db i have codes in this format:

```
xxxx xxx
```

When users search codes in this mode the result is ok
But when user search like xxxxxxx get no results.
I use this query

```
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE Data LIKE '%$search%'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: how are users entering the data? Is it a php form? If so that would make the problem a lot easier :)

Comment: Is a php form yes

Comment: awesome will post a php answer for you :)

Answer (score 1):

As my research, I have understood that your search codes fixed size. The following SQL query may work. Because I tested it with sample data.

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE Data LIKE 
CONCAT("%",TRIM(SUBSTRING('xxxx xxx',1,4))," ",TRIM(SUBSTRING('xxxx xxx' FROM 5)),"%")

SELECT * FROM data WHERE Data LIKE 
CONCAT("%",TRIM(SUBSTRING('xxxxxxx',1,4))," ",TRIM(SUBSTRING('xxxxxxx' FROM 5)),"%")
```

This was actual query I tested.

Then your query is as follows,
either

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE Data LIKE 
CONCAT("%",TRIM(SUBSTRING('$search',1,4))," ",TRIM(SUBSTRING('$search' FROM 5)),"%")
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE Data LIKE 
CONCAT("%",TRIM(SUBSTRING($search,1,4))," ",TRIM(SUBSTRING($search FROM 5)),"%")
```

Test this you may get the result.

Comment: I will test it, but i have actually 2 code format in my db 1:xxxx xxx and 2:xxx xxx In this case how the sting will be?

Comment: Can you provide me actual formats of your db codes for understanding the scenario?
Tell me how can you search keys you will enter in search?

Provide samples I will work and provide you code.....

Answer (score 0):

As you said the data gets entered via a PHP form, then we can add a space with PHP much easier than with MYSQL.

`wordwrap(trim($userInputedString) , 4 , ' ' , true );`

this will remove all whitespace from the string inputted from user, making all `XXXX XXX` strings `XXXXXXX` - then adds a space after the 4th X making the format `XXXX XXX` again. Seems illogical to trim then do it, but it assures all inputs are treated the same without having to add too many conditionals.

refs:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

## update 1

After comments down below:

to search for 3 and 4: change the 4 to a 3 and run the query again.

Answer (score -2):

Do like this-

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE REPLACE(`name`,' ','') LIKE '%$name%
```

Comment: always explain your answer never just psot